# MySQL: Indexing by column which is also a part of a compound primary keys and

Tags: mysql, index, schema

I have a table which has a compound primary key, but I would also like to query the table using one or more of the columns composing this primary key. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_visit_stats` (
  `hour` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visits` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `avg_time` float unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY  (`hour`,`user_id`,`page_id`)
)
```

So the primary key is composed of `hour`, `user_id` and `page_id`. I would like to be able to efficiently query the table on different combinations of these columns - for example to get the total visits for a page in a day or the total pages visited by a user in a week.

Does it make sense to define additional indexes on `hour`, `user_id` and `page_id` or will these indexes be redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visits for a page for a period of time:  `INDEX(page_id, hour)`

visits for a period of time:  `INDEX(hour)`

Your primary key, plus these, are not redundant; have them all.

Recommend you keep `sum_time`, not `avg_time`, then compute the avg as `SUM(sum_time) / SUM(visits)`.  (The average of averages is *not* mathematically correct.)

Comment: My plan was to `INDEX(hour)` and `INDEX(page_id)` separately, so I can make queries on each and also on both. Do you suggest I index each separately and also both? Also, thanks for the `SUM()` tip - I will look into it.

Comment: `INDEX(a,b)` replaces `INDEX(a)`, but _not_ `INDEX(b)`.  My two, plus your PK should be optimal for the use cases mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

The primary key is always indexed. This is the same for MyISAM and InnoDB, and is generally true for all storage engines that at all supports indices.

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071180/is-the-primary-key-automatically-indexed-in-mysql)

Comment: That does not answer my question. Obviously the primary is indexed - the question was weather the columns that compose the primary key are also indexed separately.